# Charge distribution in a Conductor

Tags: gauss-law, conductors

I recently read a question which even I am having a doubt in. So here it is
Suppose there are two isolated conductors both the condcutors are brought in contact now the charges will flow through the conductors so that they both have equal charges and of the same sign. Now they are again taken apart. In this configuration suppose I draw a gaussian surface as shown below. As electric field inside a conductor is always zero the flux through that surface is zero.The elctric field between the two conductors is perpendicular to the area vector and hence flux through the entire surface is zero.Which implies thag net charge present inside the gaussion surface is zero.Both these statements are contradicting each other.Could someone tell which is correct and provide a mathematical approach.[image]

Comment: The charges are on the outer surfaces

Comment: Mate the the surface that is drawn passes through the puter surface and the charge it there

Comment: Look at the surface clearly

Comment: The electric field at the surface is outward, hence there would be no electric field "inside" the metal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let both the conducting rods $A$ and $B$ contain equal charge $Q$ after being brought into contact. As electric field inside a conductor is always $0$, no charge can reside inside it but always distributes over its surface. When the two conductors in question are taken apart to the final configuration as shown in your figure, the charges on the inner surface of one, attract opposite charges on the inner surface of the other as a result of which an electric field persists in between them. However, the charges distribute over the various conducting surfaces maintaining the constraint that total charge of each conductor is $0$ . So, following the direction of the electric field $\boldsymbol E$, the entire inner surface of $A$ should have positive charge (**uniformly distributed**), say $+q$ and the entire inner surface of $B$ should have negative charge $-q$. So, the entire outer surface of $A$ has charge $Q-q$ (so that the net charge on $A$ is $Q-q+q=Q$) and the entire outer surface of $B$ has charge $Q+q$ (so that the net charge on $B$ is $Q+q-q=Q$). Now, due to uniform distribution of charges on each surface, equal amounts of positive and negative charge are enclosed by your Gaussian surface which makes the net enclosed charge $0$. Hence, this is completely consistent with Gauss' theorem as the net flux of electric field through the Gaussian surface is also $0$ as you have found out.

Hope this explains your doubt.

Comment: Thanks a lot smart turtle 4 upvotes wow

Answer (score -1):

If the two charges are equal, they will repel each other and move to the outer surfaces of the conductors. The flux and field is zero because there is no charge within your Gaussian surface.